# Text align center or margin left and margin right not centering button in CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I added a button to my HTML, and wanted to center it. I tried the two ways in the title but both of them did not work. Im new to HTML and CSS. I'm centering it using CSS but if there is a way to do it using HTML, i'm fine with that.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 110%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

div {
  height: 10em;
  position: relative
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 1000000% 1000000%;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="typing-area">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Enter</button>
  <h1>
    bocho is cool
  </h1>
</div>
```

The text box is centered, but the button is not centering.

Thanks!
Irfan

Comment: You have some very messy HTML, which may be causing the problems. Try running your HTML through the validator https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: to elaborate the comment of @RobertAKARobin: Befor the mergin of the code there where 2 body opening tags right after another. script tag after the html closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you made the size of the input 110% and left the normal page size at 100%, it pushes out the input.

```
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;            
}
```

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

you can use this instead of above

```
margin:0 auto
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex properties on parent for align to items.

You don't need to any css on button element.
This is better and new way.

```css
div#typing-area {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 110%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

div {
  height: 10em;
  position: relative
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 1000000% 1000000%;
}
```

```html
<div id="typing-area">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Enter</button>
  <h1>
    bocho is cool
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of applying align items to body as center
try this out  . Not a single CSS style required

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css "rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container row text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="text" class="w-50 ">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ">Enter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>bocho is cool</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"  integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its perfectly responsive in all 3 views